# Where Can I Find the The Setting.py File For PostgreSQL?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-settings, postgresql-14

I am trying to install PostgreSQL to work with Django. I searched my hard drive for the PostgreSQL settings.py file but could not find what I was looking for.  I found one under the PgAdmin folder (C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/pgAdmin 4/python/Lib/site-packages/azure/core/settings.py), but it does not appear to be what I'm looking for.

All of the documentation that I find says that I have to have the following in my settings.py file for PostgreSQL to work with Django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',                      
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_user_password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': 'db_port_number',
    }
}
```

I cannot find the file to place the setting in it.  Where should I be able to find it, or where should I create it?  What else should be in the file?

Comment: settings.py is part of Django configuration, not Postgres. The snippet you showed should go in your django project's settings.py file.

Comment: Thanks.  I found the settings.py file.  I appreciate you.